# How to create automate tasks on Odoo 10?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo-10, odoo

I'm trying to create a task that runs periodicaly.

I made this file on a directory called 'Data' and added it to the manifest file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
<data noupdate="1">
        <record id="ir_cron_scheduler_action" model="ir.cron">
            <field name="name">scheduler</field>
            <field name="user_id" ref="base.user_root"/>
            <field name="interval_number">1</field>
            <field name="interval_type">minutes</field>
            <field name="numbercall">-1</field>
             <field eval="False" name="doall"/>
            <field eval="'res.company'" name="model"/>
            <field eval="'refresh'" name="function"/>
         </record>
   </data>
```

and I have the following method on that model

```
def refresh(self):
    _logger.info(' This is a test')
```

But it seems is not working, doesn't print on the logger.
Any Idea?

Answer (score 2):

1. Add in you file xml  `<field eval="True" name="active" />`
2. Add in your code python

`@api.model
def  refresh(self):
    _logger.info(' This is a test')`

Answer (score 1):

As @Karaka Mohamed said, you should add `@api.model` to your method. And then, I would add some attributes to the XML like `args`, to specify empty arguments, or `nextcall`, in which you have to indicate the date of the first execution of the cron task. It should be a future date, unless you set the attribute `doall` to *True* (this will run the non-executed cron tasks of the past).

From that `nextcall` date on, your cron task will be executed every minute forever (as you specified in your definition).

An example, with this line your task will be executed for the first time five minutes after being generated:

```
<field name="args" eval="'()'"/>
<field name="nextcall" eval="(DateTime.now() + timedelta(minutes=5)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')" />
```

Warning: as you have set `<data noupdate="1">` at the top of your XML document, changes made here are not going to be updated in the database. So, you can set these changes directly in PostgreSQL, in `ir_cron` table, or you can modify the XML ID of the cron task, to create a new one the following time you upgrade your module.